# SQL Statement equivalent for Excel countif

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, count, countif

I have a column named 'cardnum' and another one named amount. (I actually have multiple other fields in the table but I'll stick with two for the example)

e.g.,

| cardnum | amount |
| --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 50 |
| ABC123 | 20 |
| ABC123 | 30 |
| ABC123 | 50 |
| XYZ720 | 24 |
| LFG475 | 35 |
| LFG475 | 100 |
| LFG475 | 0 |
| ABC123 | 50 |
| ABC123 | 20 |

Is there a SQL statement that returns a new column with the respective counts of each card number in the card number column?

It should look like this:

| cardnum | amount | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 50 | 6 |
| ABC123 | 20 | 6 |
| ABC123 | 30 | 6 |
| ABC123 | 50 | 6 |
| XYZ720 | 24 | 1 |
| LFG475 | 35 | 3 |
| LFG475 | 100 | 3 |
| LFG475 | 0 | 3 |
| ABC123 | 50 | 6 |
| ABC123 | 20 | 6 |

I tried something like this (keep in mind I applied this to my entire table with 17 columns):

```
SELECT card_number, COUNT(*) as frequency
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY card_number;
```

I also tried using `COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY...)` but it just returns all the total row count for the entire new column.

but apparently you can't use groupby with `*` or all columns either have to be part of the `groupby` or included in an aggregate function.

Comment: Using windowed `COUNT` without an `ORDER BY` clause is an option (`COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY cardnum)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using window aggregation function:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY cardnum) Count
FROM carddetails
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use following query to get your desired output.

```
SELECT A.*, B.frequency
FROM carddetails A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT cardnum, COUNT(1) frequency
    FROM carddetails
    GROUP BY cardnum
) B ON B.cardnum = A.cardnum
```

We are calculating frequency by using GROUP BY and the COUNT function.
We can populate frequency by applying JOIN on original table with result set.

We can check my execution and output on [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tH4m_MVo).

Note: When I used INNER JOIN, it sorted output on cardnum. LEFT OUTER JOIN didn't change any sequence.

Comment: A windowed aggregate would make much more sense here over a self JOIN.